# Using results from php mysql query, looping it in javascript for ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

First time using javascript and ajax here

I have a php mysqli query of customer order id's that I'm trying to write a function for in javascript that loops thru each customer order # from the previously mentioned sql array and attaches the results to an ajax (statement?) that interacts with a page that edits shipping results to on our backend shipping interface and i'm having some troubles getting it to work the way I would like it to.

The code I have so, far along with the Mysql query looks something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE shipdate IS NULL;";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>

// Function prints all open order and marks them as: Pending
$('button#printOpenOrders').on('click', function(e) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to print all open orders and mark them as pending?")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // prints all open orders
        window.open("/resources/scripts/allOpenPDF.php");
        var id = <?php json_encode($result); ?>
        id.forEach(open_orders_func);
        function open_orders_func(item) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/resources/scripts/pending-order.php?id=" + item,
                datatype : "string",
                success : function(data) {
                location.reload(true);
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

A little over my head but I feel like I'm on the right track, I'm just not getting the result I expected to get.

Comment: What is `$order`?

Comment: A mistake I made in copying and pasting my code on here. It's the $result variable from the mysqli array.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "i'm having some troubles getting it to work the way I would like it to" ?  What is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to loop the results from the mysql array so that the ajax statement will hit every item in it.

The array looks something like: [111, 112,113]
and I want ajax to hit my url + the results from that loop. I'm mostly just having issues figuring out how to loop a php array in javascript and getting it to loop into ajax.

Comment: `$result` is just one order not all orders.

Comment: `open_orders_func()` doesn't open all the orders. It performs an AJAX call and then reloads the current page.

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { $result[] = $row['id']; }`